# How do I add a count() for one table into a SQL query that has joins for multiple other tables using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sql statement that pulls data from multiple tables. This query gets all employees and their biographic information (employee id, first name, last name, badge image, etc.):

```
SELECT
e.ID as id,
e.DateTimeCreated as dateTimeCreated,
e.FullTime as fullTime,
bi.FirstName as firstName,
bi.LastName as lastName,
bi.MiddleName as middleName,
bi.DateOfBirth as dateOfBirth,
bi.PlaceOfBirth as placeOfBirth,
fr.Thumbnail as thumbnail
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN biographicinfo bi
ON e.ID = bi.employeeId
LEFT JOIN facialraw fr
ON e.ID = fr.EnrollmentId
AND fr.CaptureAngle = 2
GROUP BY e.ID
```

Now, there is another table called, say, EmployeeDiscrepencies that I would like to do a count on:

```
select count(1) as "Discrepencies" from EmployeeDiscrepencies ed where ed.employeeId = 2;
```

I would like to add this count statement into my original query when I grab all employees, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I wanted to try something like this:

```
SELECT
e.ID as id,
e.DateTimeCreated as dateTimeCreated,
e.FullTime as fullTime,
bi.FirstName as firstName,
bi.LastName as lastName,
bi.MiddleName as middleName,
bi.DateOfBirth as dateOfBirth,
bi.PlaceOfBirth as placeOfBirth,
fr.Thumbnail as thumbnail,
ed.count(1), -- need a "where" clause here
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN biographicinfo bi
ON e.ID = bi.employeeId
LEFT JOIN facialraw fr
ON e.ID = fr.EnrollmentId
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDiscrepencies ed
on e.ID = ed.employeeID
AND fr.CaptureAngle = 2
GROUP BY e.ID
```

As you can guess, it is not working

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only that counter from `EmployeeDiscrepencies` then the simplest way is to use a subquery to return it like this:

```
SELECT
e.ID as id,
e.DateTimeCreated as dateTimeCreated,
e.FullTime as fullTime,
bi.FirstName as firstName,
bi.LastName as lastName,
bi.MiddleName as middleName,
bi.DateOfBirth as dateOfBirth,
bi.PlaceOfBirth as placeOfBirth,
fr.Thumbnail as thumbnail,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmployeeDiscrepencies ed WHERE e.ID = ed.employeeID) as Discrepencies
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN biographicinfo bi
ON e.ID = bi.employeeId
LEFT JOIN facialraw fr
ON e.ID = fr.EnrollmentId
AND fr.CaptureAngle = 2
GROUP BY e.ID
```

If your condition is for employeeId = 2 only then a cross join of your query to the subquery would be more efficient:

```
SELECT
e.ID as id,
e.DateTimeCreated as dateTimeCreated,
e.FullTime as fullTime,
bi.FirstName as firstName,
bi.LastName as lastName,
bi.MiddleName as middleName,
bi.DateOfBirth as dateOfBirth,
bi.PlaceOfBirth as placeOfBirth,
fr.Thumbnail as thumbnail,
ed.counter as Discrepencies
FROM employee e
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM EmployeeDiscrepencies ed WHERE  ed.employeeID = 2) ed
LEFT JOIN biographicinfo bi
ON e.ID = bi.employeeId
LEFT JOIN facialraw fr
ON e.ID = fr.EnrollmentId
AND fr.CaptureAngle = 2
GROUP BY e.ID
```

Comment: Sweet ... that edit you made, where there is not a specific ID, worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `CROSS JOIN` has a specific meaning in sqlite; it prevents the query planner from reordering tables in the join. It should only be used when the best order isn't being picked automatically.

Comment: What order? The OP needs a single value that is returned by the subquery in every row of the table, so either a cross join to that subquery will do it or by placing directly the result of the subquery as a column like the 1st query. Nothing more nothing less.

Comment: Just leave out the `CROSS`. Details at https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#crossjoin

Comment: The link that you posted refers to 3 tables that need to be cross joined and the optimizer *is free to reorder the tables of FROM clause anyway it sees fit*. The current case involves 1 table that is cross joined to the subquery and 2 other tables LEFT joined to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you - I did it quick and did not check for error so just make sure all closing/opening brackets are in correct place.

```
   SELECT
   e.ID as id,
   e.DateTimeCreated as dateTimeCreated,
   e.FullTime as fullTime,
   bi.FirstName as firstName,
   bi.LastName as lastName,
   bi.MiddleName as middleName,
   bi.DateOfBirth as dateOfBirth,
   bi.PlaceOfBirth as placeOfBirth,
   fr.Thumbnail as thumbnail,
   [EmployeeDis].[Discrepencies] 
FROM
   employee e 
OUTER APPLY ( 
   select
      count(1) as [Discrepencies] 
   from
      EmployeeDiscrepencies ed 
   where
      ed.employeeId = 2;
) as [EmployeeDis] 
      LEFT JOIN
         biographicinfo bi 
         ON e.ID = bi.employeeId 
      LEFT JOIN
         facialraw fr 
         ON e.ID = fr.EnrollmentId 
         AND fr.CaptureAngle = 2 
   GROUP BY
      e.ID
```

Comment: See, it's that `where ed.employeeId = 2` that I cannot use as I want to use every Employee ID that comes through in the outer query.

Comment: That's not valid sqlite syntax.

Comment: Yes Shawn - only see the tag now.